Suppose that $-1\leq ax^2 + bx + c\leq 1$ for $-1\leq x\leq 1$, where $a, b$ and $c$ are real numbers, prove that $-4\leq 2ax + b\leq 4$.
I see that for $x = 0, |c|\leq 1$, for $x = -1, |a - b + c|\leq 1$ and for $x = 1, |a + b + c|\leq 1$.
Thus, $|2a + 2c|\leq 2\Rightarrow |2a|< 4$ and $|b|\leq 1$.
This, gives me $|2a + b|\leq 5$, which is wrong. I do not understand what mistake I am doing.
Edit: The question suggested by Martin R does provide the solution but I do not understand my mistake from the given solution.

Does this answer your question? Quadratic inequality with boundaries – found with Approach0

Yes and no. It provides a solution but does not tell me mistake in my methods.

$|2a + b|\leq 5$ is not wrong, just not good enough.

How did you come up with the bound $\vert 2a+b\vert \leq 2$? Moreover, your answer is not wrong, but it is not the best possible upper bound.

@user1008978 Because $|2a|\leq 4$ and $|b|\leq 1$ so $|2a + b|\leq 5$

@MartinR I understand what you mean.

So, basically, what you are saying is: if the values of a parabola are bounded, its slope should too :-)

@Dominique Well, the question puts even smaller boundary.

What about trying to maximise the slope? Start with an extremum at $x=-1$, get to the maximal (or minimal) value for $x=1$ and calculate the slope of the retrieved quadratic equation.

There's no mistake; you just haven't solved the problem yet.
Here's a hint on how to solve it. Let $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. Then
$$p(x\pm 1) - p(x) = a(x \pm 1)^2 + b(x \pm 1) + c - ax^2 - bx - c$$
$$= \pm(2ax + b) + a$$
Now use that $|a| \leq 2$ in the right way....
